# Word wrapping for short strings in parentheses

Tags: pdftex, pandoc

I have a markdown file that I process with pandoc.  I have the following text in the .md file:

```
**Note:** The entire text above would be entered on a single command line
without the backslash (`\`).
```

Pandoc generates the following LaTeX code:

```
\textbf{Note:} The entire text above would be entered on a single
command line without the backslash (\texttt{\textbackslash{}}).
```

The output that is generated using pdflatex causes the to cause the open parenthesis `(` to be on line one and the remaining `\).` to be on the next line.

I have redefined `\texttt` with the following:

```
\let\OldTexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1][%
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \exhyphenpenalty=10000
    \setlength{\emergencystretch}{6em}
    \sethlcolor{codegray}%
    {\ttfamily\hl{#1}}%
}
```

So, my question is, how can I prevent one letter be on one line and the rest of the "word" to be on the next?  Basically, I want to not have word wrapping after a single character.

Comment: There shouldn't be a break point behind the `(`, unless your document ist doing something curious. Show a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: are you sure there is no space after the `(` ? Please show an example code.

Comment: Postive.  That was the first thing I looked for.  The above is exactly as it is in the file.

Comment: then please fix your example so that people can see the issue, as with default settings there would be no break after `(` so you are asking about code you have not shown, which makes it hard to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting a space before the texttt with your redefinition. Hide it with a comment sign:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\let\OldTexttt\texttt
\usepackage{soul}

\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{%
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \exhyphenpenalty=10000
    \setlength{\emergencystretch}{6em}%< hide this space
    \sethlcolor{codegray}%
    {\ttfamily\hl{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Note:} The entire text above would be entered on a single
command line without the backslash (\texttt{\textbackslash{}}).

\end{document}
```

Be aware that your penalty settings are not grouped and so will affect following text.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I new I missed something subtle.  I also put a `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` around the start and end of this macro.